# Shadowplay will not recognize Overwatch

Tags: overwatch, shadowplay

Shadowplay is the only piece of recording software available to me at this moment and it does not recognize Overwatch at all.

It seems it doesn't matter if Overwatch is in fullscreen or in borderless windowed, shadowplay simply doesn't even know Overwatch exists.

Shadowplay works fine with any of my fullscreen Steam games but for Overwatch it just won't work.

Have any of you found a solution to getting Shadowplay to recognize Overwatch, thus allowing me to record gameplay sessions through it?

Drivers are now up-to-date; recording has yet to work.  I don't use preset recording times and record everything manually.

Comment: Huh, it works fine for me with the default settings.  Do you have the latest Nvidia Experience + drivers?

Comment: I had similar problems with AMDs Plays.tv and fixed them by making sure that Rivatuner didn't run. Do you have another overlay-program running?

Comment: @Nijin22 I don't believe so; I've never used any other recording software besides Shadowplay and I'm pretty sure I don't have any overlays running

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I just finished updating my Nvidia Graphic Drivers, then restarted my system, and tried recording and it still doesn't work.  But now they are up to date. (version 368.22)

Comment: Is the ShadowPlay button icon green or red?

Comment: Are you using Windows 10? If so, have you tried the Windows Game Bar (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/keyboard-shortcuts-for-game-bar)?

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Enable "Allow desktop capture" in the preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shadowplay to record overwatch in fullscreen mode.

In the preferences check "Allow desktop capture" and you will be able to record overwatch in fullscreen mode.

[image]

I set the pause/break key to trigger manual recording because F11 is reserved for things in certain games

Comment: Is that slower than letting shadowplay capture just the game or is there no preformance difference?

Comment: that's a good question, I record at 2560 x 1600 with all settings turned up to ultra/epic etc, i get a delay when i hit manual record because i use external drives that sometimes sleep when not used. once the drive wakes up recording is smooth, i'm using i7 intel cpu with 16gb ram and gtx 690 graphics card. i haven't bothered with the background recording features of shadowplay much to avoid using unnecessary resources, but i think it's a great idea, because loads of times when i wanted to hit manual record i wish i could have recorded things from 5 minutes earlier

Comment: @MadMrCrazy i'm not sure at all

Answer (score 0):

Shadowplay seems to only recognize Overwatch when it is in fullscreen mode, in stead of borderless windowed.

Comment: He says fullscreen mode doesn't work

Comment: You're absolutely right. Looks like I failed to read it correctly.

Comment: If you allow desktop capture then you can record overwatch in full screen mode